# Vehicle Routing with Multiple trips (VRPMT)

Tags: jsprit

I am pretty new to jsprit and was wondering if there is an easy way to do vehicle routing with multiple trips.

Example:
1 depot with a large supply of packages(~100) weighing from 0-5 pounds and 1 vehicle able to carry 15 lbs at a time. I have a 240 minute window so I would like the vehicle to take multiple trips. After each trip the vehicle can get more packages from the depot.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model your jobs as shipments (rather than services) starting from your depot. Then you should be able model multiple trips from the depot to your customers.